# Implementation of AJP protocol in Java

Tags: java, client, ajp

From Apache, you can use the "mod_jk" module to send HTTP requests to Tomcat using the "AJP" protocol, which is far more efficient that HTTP itself.

I want to do the same, but from a Java program. I want to use "AJP" because of its good performances (and Tomcat is not bad after all).

Does someone know about a Java implementation of the client side of "AJP" ?

Comment: I won't give this as an answer (to keep the question appear as unanswered) but note: If you are sooner or later communicating through the internet, you'll probably get firewall issues. As http clients are definitely more in use you'll get more robust implementations (and better support) there.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the tomcat-ajp.jar present in %TOMCAT_HOME%/server/lib have the AJP implementation?

Answer (score 1):

There's open source Apache [ajp-client](https://github.com/jrialland/ajp-client) available if someone needs it:

> This is a java implementation of an ajp13 client, allowing to send requests to a servlet container using this protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Whithout any real idea, but have you looked into Tomcat's source code, yet? Maybe Tomcat doesn't just implement the receiving end of AJP.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like tomcat only receives- the sending side is written in C as an apache module.